# JQuery - Appending search strings and redirecting to results page

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following html form:

```
<form action="results.html">
Search: <input type="text" id="search">
<input type="submit" id="submitBtn" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I have the following JQuery code which appends the users search term to the forms 'action' attribute, then redirects to the results page where I will carry out search processing.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#submitBtn").click( function(event) {
        var st = $(this).parent().attr('action') + "?searchTerm=" + $("#search").val();
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().attr('action',st);
        $(location).attr('href', st);
   });
});
```

This seems very long winded to me. Is there a better way to do this with JQuery?

Comment: You could use AJAX instead, but that would involve changing the output of your `results.html` page and is a bit broad for a single question.

Comment: just add a name to your input and method = GET to your form

Answer (score 0):

You need javascript to pass value as GET :

```
<form method="GET" action="results.html">
    Search: <input type="text" name="searchTerm" id="search">
    <input type="submit" id="submitBtn" value="Submit">
</form>
```